# undefined method `collect' for 2:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, google-visualization

```
def function1
   @user=User.find(params[:user_id])
   @participants=Participant.find_all_by_user_id(params[:user_id])
    bar_1_data = @user.get_total
    bar_2_data = params[:count]
    color_1 = 'c53711'
    color_2 = '0000ff'
    min=0
    max=100
    puts(bar_1_data)      # prints 2 on console
    puts(bar_2_data)      # prints 3 on console
    puts (bar_1_data).is_a? Integer # prints true
    puts (bar_2_data).is_a? Integer # prints false
    bc=GoogleChart::BarChart.new("300x80", " ", :horizontal, false)
    bc.data " ", [100], 'ffffff'
    bc.data "Bar1", bar_1_data, color_1
    bc.data "Bar2", bar_2_data.to_i, color_2
    bc.axis :x, :range => [min,max]
    bc.show_legend = true
    bc.stacked = false
    bc.data_encoding = :extended
    @bc= bc.to_url
    end
  end
```

I am getting the argument error "comparison of String with 100 failed" int the above controller code. Then I changed the lines

```
bc.data "Bar1", bar_1_data, color_1
bc.data "Bar2", bar_2_data, color_2
```

to

```
bc.data "Bar1", bar_1_data.to_i, color_1
bc.data "Bar2", bar_2_data.to_i, color_2
```

which gives me `undefined method collect for 2:Fixnum` at line `@bc= bc.to_url`. 
On console it gives the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `collect' for 2:Fixnum):
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/base.rb:499:in `extended_encode'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/base.rb:461:in `encode_data'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/bar_chart.rb:69:in `process_data'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/bar_chart.rb:68:in `collect'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/bar_chart.rb:68:in `process_data'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/base.rb:440:in `add_data'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/base.rb:305:in `prepare_params'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/base.rb:77:in `to_url'
  app/controllers/assess_controller.rb:139:in `function1'
  gchartrb (0.8) lib/google_chart/bar_chart.rb:22:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/assess_controller.rb:131:in `new'
  app/controllers/assess_controller.rb:131:in `function1'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11/lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'

Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

Tried printing `bc` in the view as `<p><img src="<%= puts (@bc) %>" ></p>`,it doesn't print anything, but when I am printing `bc` in the controller it prints 
`#<GoogleChart::BarChart:0x103be9660>`.

Am I not sending it correctly to the view? I have tried both `@bc=bc.to_url` and `puts bc.to_url` as in http://gchartrb.rubyforge.org/.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `bc.data "Bar1", bar_1_data.map(&:to_i), color_1` ?

Comment: gives `undefined method `map' for 2:Fixnum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the api for google charts, I see this:

```
bc.data " ", [100], 'ffffff'
bc.data "Bar1", bar_1_data, color_1
bc.data "Bar2", bar_2_data.to_i, color_2
```

The parameters of the first line are of type String, Array, String.

The parameters of the next two are String, Fixnum, String

Your error message is `undefined method collect for 2:Fixnum` ... so perhaps you should change the Fixnum to Array.

```
bc.data " ", [100], 'ffffff'
bc.data "Bar1", [bar_1_data], color_1
bc.data "Bar2", [bar_2_data.to_i], color_2
```

Comment: As an addendum to my own answer, in the case that `bar_1_data` can be either a single value or an array, you can handle both with `Array(bar_1_data)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're loading bar_1_data and bar_2_data into arrays. Thus the error `undefined method to_i for Array`.

Instead of:

```
bar_1_data = [@user.get_total]
bar_2_data = [params[:count]]
```

Just try

```
bar_1_data = @user.get_total
bar_2_data = params[:count]
```

Note that putting your data inside `[]` brackets means it's now an array of one item.

Comment: I removed the brackets, but now its giving me `undefined methodcollect' for 2:Fixnum` error at line `@bc= bc.to_url`

Comment: Well, this is the answer to the question you asked. You were trying to compare an array to an integer, which will not work, and also you cannot convert an array to an integer.   Now you have a problem with this GoogleCharts library you're calling, and I think you'll need to ask a new question focusing in on the correct usage of that library. I have no idea what the `to_url` method needs in order to work, but clearly it is expecting an enumerable where it is getting an integer, so you'll have to fix that.